# How to determine if a degree sequence is a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given an arbitrary degree sequence in the form of ${v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_n}$ with n elements, if asked to show that it is a graph or not, how can one methodically answer in terms of n and the magnitude of $v_i$

Comment: The [Erdős-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) completely solves the problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm